Hide point after company as author in biblatex
I'm currently facing an issue with biblatex and apa6. When I try to use a company as author (double curly braces or not) there is always a dot behind it in the bibliography.
For example:
Europäische Union. (2016): VERORDNUNG (EU) 2016/679 DES EUROPÄISCHEN
PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES. Abgerufen am 19. April 2024 von https://eur- lex.europa.
eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=DE
Where it should be:
Europäische Union (2016): VERORDNUNG (EU) 2016/679 DES EUROPÄISCHEN
PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES. Abgerufen am 19. April 2024 von https://eur- lex.europa.
eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=DE
My setup:
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

@misc{euDsgvo,
author = {{Europäische Union}},
title  = {VERORDNUNG (EU) 2016/679 DES EUROPÄISCHEN PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES},
year   = {2016},
url    = {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=DE}
urldate = {2024-04-19}
}
Is there anyone that knows how to solve this? It's a requirement of my university.
I already tried to use {\nopunct} behind the company name, but this way, it deletes the comma behind the company in the footnote as well.
Thank you very much!

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

apa 6 requires a dot there. Why are you using the style? Is that a requirement too?

@UlrikeFischer Yes, apa is the requirement and my university has a few examples, where there is no dot behind the company name.

Then tell your university that they got it wrong. If they require apa 6 they should accept its rules. See e.g. https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/07/punctuating-the-reference-list-entry.html.

Ulrike Fischer is right, this is intentional behavior in the apa6 style.
Regardless, your goal can be achieved with this code:
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@misc{euDsgvo,
author = {{Europäische Union}},
title = {VERORDNUNG (EU) 2016/679 DES EUROPÄISCHEN PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES},
year = {2016},
url = {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=DE},
urldate = {2024-04-19}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


